# Looping through a Map Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a function called `Saveck(aid: number)`

```
Saveck(aid: number) {
    const modelsToChange: any[] = [];
    const model: any = {};
    for (const value of this.submittedCheckAnswers.values()) {
          model.AssignmentId = assignmentId;
          model.QaId = value.qaId;
          model.Action = 'Insert';
          console.log(model);
          modelsToChange.push(model);
    }
    console.log(modelsToChange);
}
```

submittedCheckAnswers is a map that was initialized properly **before** getting into this for loop.

```
console.log(this.submittedCheckAnswers) will give the following result:

Map(2) {2 => {…}, 3 => {…}}
  [[Entries]]
    0: {2 => Object}
      key: 2
      value:
        answerId: 5
        answerContext: "9"
        aOrdinal: 2
        isAnswer: false
        ngAnswerId: "Answer2"
        ngAnswerField: ""
        qaId: 56
        __proto__: Object
    1: {3 => Object}
      key: 3
      value:
        answerId: 6
        answerContext: "8"
        aOrdinal: 3
        isAnswer: false
        ngAnswerId: "Answer3"
        ngAnswerField: ""
        qaId: 57
```

The command `console.log(model);` inside the for loop is giving the following results:
// first time

```
{AssignmentId: 1, QaId: 56, Action: "Insert"}
  AssignmentId: 1
  QaId: 57
  Action: "Insert"
```

// second time

```
{AssignmentId: 1, QaId: 57, Action: "Insert"}
  AssignmentId: 1
  QaId: 57
  Action: "Insert"
```

No, I did not make a typo in **QaId** while copying and pasting the object indicated in the first time. For some weird reason, the object prints on the console like this `{AssignmentId: 1, QaId: 56, Action: "Insert"}` with `QaId: 56` but when I expand the object

```
AssignmentId: 1
QaId: 57
Action: "Insert"
```

the QaId is 57!!!! I can't seem to understand why? This 57 is being inserted in the model and appended to the modelsToChange. Thus, modelsToChange is wrong.

Can someone explains to me what is going on?

Comment: You are pushing references to the same `model` object into the array multiple times, so they will all have whatever the last value you set happens to be.

Comment: Oh man, what the hell is wrong with me. Thanks a lot @JaredSmith